Fourier transform of incomplete gamma function
Ultimately I am interested in the Fourier transform of
$$
e^{-i\zeta}(-i\zeta)^{-2\epsilon}\Gamma(2\epsilon,-i\zeta)
$$
in a series expansion around $\epsilon=0$, so to first order in
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d}\zeta}{2\pi}\, e^{i\zeta(x-1)} (-i\zeta)^{-2\epsilon}\Gamma(2\epsilon,-i\zeta).
$$
Assuming that limit and integral can be exchanged, the first order term would be
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d}\zeta}{2\pi}\, e^{i\zeta(x-1)} \Gamma(0,-i\zeta)\,.
$$
This can be computed with Mathematica either using Integrate or via FourierTransform and the result is $0$.
On the other hand, getting the antiderivative $F(\zeta)$ and computing
$$
\lim_{L\to\infty}(F(L)-F(-L))
$$
seems to suggest a function $\mathrm{sign}(-x)/(1-x)$ (by using the Limit function and testing some $x$ values). Here clearly $x=1$ is a singular point, where a distributional result might become necessary, but let's ignore that for now.
A further possibility is to use the integral representation of the incomplete gamma function
$$
\Gamma(n,-i\zeta) = \int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}\tau\, e^{-(-i\zeta+\tau)} (-i\zeta+\tau)^{n-1}
$$
and then exchange the Fourier integration over $\zeta$ with the $\tau$ integration. The result of this procedure is $\theta(-x)(1-x)$.
For some context, this is a problem that appears in nuclear/particle physics and $\epsilon$ is the shift from four dimensions $D=4-2\epsilon$.
From a physics point of view there is some motivation for the result to be $\theta(-x)(1-x)$, but maybe there are problems in this being well-defined. There are singular points, for example $\epsilon$ regulates the gamma function for $\zeta\to0$. So the exchange of limit and integration in the first step might already be one of the problems.
I would hope for a discussion of the problems here, or at least pointers in the right direction. In particular: why does Mathematica integrate this to zero; in what theory of the integral would this be the case?
In[1] := Integrate[ Exp[I*(x - 1)*zeta]*Gamma[0, -I*zeta], {zeta, -Infinity, Infinity}]
Out[1] = ConditionalExpression[0, Element[x, Reals]]

In fact, even when regulating the Gamma function via Gamma[2\epsilon, -I*zeta], Mathematica finds $0$ assuming that $-1/2 < \epsilon < 1/2$.

I believe your integral can be evaluated as
$$F_T(x)=\mathcal{F}_{\zeta}[\Gamma(0,-i \zeta )](x-1)=\underset{T\to\infty}{\text{lim}} \left(\int\limits_{-T}^T \Gamma(0,-i \zeta)\, e^{i (x-1) \zeta} \, d\zeta\right)\\=\underset{T\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{-2\, \text{Ci}(T) \sin(T (x-1))+2\, \text{Si}(T x)+(\pi-2\, \text{Si}(T)) \cos (T (x-1))-\pi }{x-1}\right)\tag{1}$$

Figure (1) below illustrates formula (1) above for $F_T(x)$ evaluated at $T=1,000,000$. I believe $F_T(x)=0$ for $x>0$, $F_T(0)=\pi$, and $\underset{\epsilon \to 0^+}{\text{lim}}F_T(-\epsilon )=2 \pi$.

Figure (1): Illustration of formula (1) for $F_T(x)$

I believe
$$F(x)=\lim\limits_{T\to\infty} F_T(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}  \frac{\pi}{1-x} (\text{sgn}(-x)+1) & x\le 0 \\  0 & x>0 \\ \end{array}\right.=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}  \frac{2 \pi}{1-x} & x<0 \\  \pi & x=0 \\  0 & x>0 \\ \end{array}\right.\tag{2}$$
since Mathematica indicates
$$\mathcal{F}_x^{-1}[F(x+1)](\zeta )=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(x+1)\, e^{-i \zeta x} \, dx=\Gamma (0,-i \zeta)\,,\quad\zeta\in\mathbb{R}\tag{3}.$$

Thanks, this confirms the support I find when using the integral representation of the incomplete gamma function in Mathematica. I would still be curious about why Mathematica naively finds 0, but this might be more an internal Mathematica question, rather than maths.

@Tobias Perhaps Mathematica is confused about the condition ($x\in\mathbb{R}$ versus $x>0$).

Looks like it, there is definitely something fishy going on. Without assumptions it claims $0$ if x ∈ R. With assumption x>0, it's zero, OK. With assumption x<0 it returns $\frac{\pi -i \log ((x-2) x)}{x-1}$. Sounds like a bug report is in order.

All of this is with Mathematica 14, with 12 I also get zero assuming $x<0$... as usual one cannot trust Mathematica with trickier integrals :(.

@Tobias Is $$\lim\limits_{T\to\infty} F_T(x)=\left{\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{\pi}{1-x} (\text{sgn}(-x)+1) & x\le 0 \
0 & x>0 \
\end{array}\right.=\left{\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{2 \pi}{1-x} & x<0 \
\pi & x=0 \
0 & x>0 \
\end{array}\right.$$ correct?

I believe that is correct, as far as one decides to compute it this way. I think what Mathematica might be doing is to compute $[0,\infty)$ + $(-\infty,0]$. At least it's able to compute those separately, and the sum is zero. But I also find that the individual halves with limits L->infinity (numerically) reproduce the individual halves where one has directly integrated to infinity. There must be something wrong happening with some simplification. I'll have to look more into that.

I think the culprit is, that it is taking a different branch for one of the involved functions when directly computing the integral to infinity. Now this brings me to the question whether my original integral is ambiguous, and whether it is fixed by the original expression with full eps dependence (e.g. assuming eps>0 or eps<0). Unfortunately I haven't managed to compute the integral with full eps dependence and then expand, so far.
